# Xcode 4 - old shortcuts

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode4

recently the `Xcode 4` was released and it's totally different from the `3.x.x` versions.

I wander if some of you already found equivalents or similar functionalities that the `3.x.x` version + old `Interface Builder`  had like the following shortcuts:

```
cmd+b - bold font in Interface Builder
cmd+shift+"=" (cmd+ "+") = bigger font (I.B.)
cmd+"-" = smaller font (I.B.)
cmd+up arrow - switching from the .h to .m file of the same class
```

Answer (score 2):

> cmd+up arrow - switching from the .h to .m file of the same class

This one is `ctrl+command+up` now, or `ctrl+option+command+up` to open in a split pane side by side.

I don't think it's possible to change fonts by shortcuts any more, since they don't use the standard font menu any more. But I might be wrong.